# Prevent API push from running multiple times while saving

Tags: c#, database, ef-code-first, saving-data

After our orders are complete we want to push them to our ERP. We got this working to today but we have one problem and that is that the can be pushed multiple times.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Update(Order order) {
    if(order.Id > 0 && order.PushedToErp == false)
        order.PushedToErp = _erpService.PushToErp(order);

    _unitOfWork.Orders.Update(order);

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, order);
}
```

Problem with this code is that if the push takes to long and the user refreshes the page and saves the order again the order will be pushed twice since the bool is not set yet.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control the amount of time a client waits for a request to complete.

If this is call that takes long you should move to a worker process that would be responsible for doing that work.